# Can PNY Enterprise SSDs work in Dell R710 with Perc H700?

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, ssd, dell-perc, h700

To improve the performance of a Dell R710 running CentOS 7.2 and being used as a MongoDB server, I'd like to add SSDs. The PNY Enterprise SSDs (specifically the 240GB EP7011) seem reasonably priced. But will those SSD drives work in an R710 with a Perc H700?  Will the controller recognize them? I searched, but have not found information either for or against this combination.

(We don't have a service contract with Dell.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running firmware released in the past few years (latest = safest bet), non-Dell branded/certified drives are not "blocked", and the controller will use them just as any other SATA SSD. Assuming PNY's SSDs properly adhere to SATA specifications, you're not likely to see any compatibility issues.
A problem you may want to test for and be aware of though: That generation of PERC controller was not truly designed with SSD performance in mind, and the card itself may become a bottleneck under certain workloads. Load test, set a baseline, and be sure you know what to expect before throwing production data on it!

Comment: Also, be aware that PERC controller does not support SCSI UNMAP commands. Thankfully PNY's enterprise SSDs use SandForce flash controllers, which are known for having good garbage collection.

Comment: For anyone looking at this - the comment on the H700/H710 raid controllers being maxed out with SSDs in RAID is true - it will be the bottleneck because it uses a PCIE GenII interface which will become saturated with more than one or two modern SSDs in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your [computer's manual](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/r710-spec-sheet.pdf) shows that it supports SSD and SATA so that is a big **yes**.  They are compatible without any doubt.

Comment: Yes, I know, the Perc H700 spec says it supports 2.5" SSDs, but unless I'm mistaken, the EP7011 is of a newer generation than the R710 and H700. While I can upgrade the latter's firmware, I do not feel this is "without any doubt" a combination that will work. Thus, I wanted to ask around before buying the stuff.

Comment: Not sure what worries you.  If you want to make sure that your new hardware is exploited to its maximum, you either buy a new computer to go with it or buy and older drive.  Of course that doesn't make sense one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes to this and wonders about the final answer, it is *yes*.  I bought the SSDs, installed them, and everything worked without a hitch.  The system has been running nicely for weeks.